# If$ A =PDP^{t}$, prove that A is a self adjoint operator

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

This was a question in my linear algebra course. Can Someone please check If what I've done is correct?

Prove that If $A = PDP^{t}$, where $D$ is the diagonal matrix, and $P$ the matrix with eigenvectors of $A$ as columns, that $A$ is symmetric.

If $A$ by hypothesis is symmetric, it's correct to say that:
$$
<Av,w> = <v, A^{t}w>
$$

Se want to prove that the equality above is correct for our $A$, so we get:

$$
<pdp^t v,w> = < v, (pdp^t)^t w>
$$

$$
<pdp^t v,w> = < v, dpp^t w>
$$

But $dp = pd$, hence

$$<pdp^t v,w> = < v, pdp^t w>$$

So $A$ is indeed symmetric.

Comment: How did you get $(pdp^t)^t = d p p^t$? Generally $(abc)^t = c^t b ^t a ^t$.

Comment: It's just because DP = PD that I wrote that way...

Comment: Whether a **matrix** is symmetric is an intrinsic property of the matrix itself, but whether a **linear operator** is self-adjoint [depends on the inner product](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2110967). The question asks you to prove that $A$ is symmetric, without referring to any inner product. You should state what inner product (such as the Euclidean inner product if the matrices are real) you are using.

Comment: Why is $dp=pd$?

Comment: If $A=P D P^T$ then $A^T = P D^T P^T = P D P^T = A$.

Comment: @user1551 Yeah, I'm using euclidean inner product

Comment: @copper.hat That's what I've concluded, but using inner product... So my answer is correct right?

Comment: If it is the standard inner product then yes.

Comment: Yes it is. Thank you for answering my friend. I was afraid. It was a question in my test haha